# returning three values from a function

Tags: c++, tuples, stdtuple

Hi I wanted to implement tuple.
Let me know what is going wrong in this and how to implement it correctly. I want to return three values from an function where the first values will be Integers and the last value will be an array.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct t_untuple
{
    T1& a1;
    T2& a2;
    T3& a3;
    explicit t_untuple(T1& a1, T2& a2, T3& a3) : a1(a1), a2(a2), a3(a3) { }

t_untuple<T1, T2, T3>& operator = (const tuple <T1, T2, T3>& p)
    {
        a1 = p.first;
        a2 = p.second;
        a3 = p.third;
        return *this;
    }
};

// Our functor helper (creates it)
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
t_untuple<T1, T2, T3> unpair(T1& a1, T2& a2, T3& a3)
{
    return t_unpair<T1, T2, T3>(a1, a2, a3);
}
```

Help me out in this.

I am getting **Symbol 'tuple' could not be resolved** at const tuple & p due to which the p.third is also an error

Comment: What happens when you try to use it?

Comment: why not create a class that contains int,int, std::array<T> (assuming that T varies)

Comment: Can you help out how to do it. I am not sure how I can proceed now.

Comment: what is the array? is it always string for example or do you need to vary it?

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Comment: what is `t_unpair` and should it be `t_untuple`?

Comment: Create class, make 3 members (int, int, array) and create the functions to set them and return this class. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: Where is `t_unpair` defined? And try `std::tuple` instead of just `tuple`.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just use `std::tuple`?

Comment: No there is no reason. I can use anything. I just need to return three values from an function out of which the array value will become an input parameter to another function.

Comment: Than why do you bother with all that? Return the struct having your 3 members in it. Easiest and suits you nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what types you want to return, why dont you use a simple struct:

```
template <typename T>
struct return_type {
    int a;
    int b;
    std::array<T> c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to expand code from using `unpair` and `std::pair`:

```
t_untuple<T1, T2, T3>& operator = (const tuple <T1, T2, T3>& p)
    {
        a1 = p.first;
        a2 = p.second;
        a3 = p.third;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

but access fields of tuple are done different way:

```
t_untuple<T1, T2, T3>& operator = (const std::tuple <T1, T2, T3>& p)
    {
        a1 = std::get<0>(p);
        a2 = std::get<1>(p);
        a3 = std::get<2>(p);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

you also need to replace `unpair` to `untuple` in your copy-paste:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
t_untuple<T1, T2, T3> untuple(T1& a1, T2& a2, T3& a3)
{
    return t_untuple<T1, T2, T3>(a1, a2, a3);
}
```

do not forget to `#include <tuple>` and you have to make sure that you compiler is at least in c++11 mode

Comment: Hi, I am geeting this error when I implemented your code.

 error: 'tuple' does not name a type
  t_untuple<T1, T2, T3>& operator = (const tuple <T1, T2, T3>& p)

Comment: change to `std::tuple` and do not forget include as I added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming array type is invariant. Either use std::tuple

```
std::tuple<int,int,std::array<std::string>> MyFunc()
```

here is man page http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

or create concrete class

```
struct IIA
{
    int a;
    int b;
    std::array<std::string> arr;
}

IAA Myfunc(){}
```

Comment: He already is using `std::tuple`, he wants to create helper to unpack values